# Zend route with dynamic composite action?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

Is there any way to write a Zend route with dynamic composite action, meaning an action that combines more than one matched pattern or a combination of a matched pattern with a static text?

Example:

```
uri -> desired action
/company/unique-product-code/overview -> product-overview
/company/unique-product-code/gallery -> product-gallery
/company/unique-product-code/... -> product-...
```

Current code (that does not work):

```
$regexp = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    '^(company)/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/?',
    array(),
    array(1 => 'controller', 2 => 'productCode', 'product-3' => 'action')
);
```

Comment: is product code all alpha and lower?

Comment: I can change the pattern to [a-zA-Z-]+, but it is not the problem

Comment: and this is the last route being added to the router?

Comment: Presumably that last bit should be `'3' => 'action'`?

Comment: yes, I need to make the action be word 'product' + dash + 3rd regexp match

Answer (score 1):

I have a found a few answers to your question.  I guess it all depends on how you want to structure your Zend Framework Software.

From my understanding, you have a controller called Company.  Then, it has various actions that include productOverviewAction(), etc.

So, here are a few 'almost there' solutions - and then I'll solve your current dilema. :)

**First Possible Answer**

You may want to use the controller Company for company specific information.  Perhaps you'll make a controller called Product for product information.  Then, you would actually want to go to something like /product/[unique-id]/overview - nice URL.  Here's the route to match that:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'product/:productCode/:action',
    array(
        'controller'=>'product'
    )
);
```

As you see, it's not even a regular expression, so it can be fast!

**Second Possible Answer**

The reason you need the regular expression is because the action does not match the url, but is made of part of it.  However, let's say you changed Company::productOverviewAction() to Company::OverviewAction() - you then could use this route:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'company/:productCode/:action',
    array(
        'controller'=>'company'
    )
);
```

However, I know that's not exactly what you asked...

**The Almost Exact Answer**

Without doing modifications to the routing class, you can use the following router:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'company/:productCode/:action',
    array(
        'controller'=>'company'
    )
);
```

And then, since it gets directed to each action, you can proxy the actions in the CompanyController.  For example:

```
public function overviewAction()
{
    return $this->productOverviewAction();
}
```

*Note: I did not use _forward() as not to redispatch (I think that happens...)

Best of luck!

Comment: I do currently use your solution #2, which was also mentioned in the answer by @TimFountain which I implemented before asking this question. However, I chose to ask it exactly due to now knowing if solution to it is even possible. +1 for taking the time and for the details.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought through it and I really WANTED to solve it - but I kept thinking - its just not gonna work without creating a brand new router... glad you have something that works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think this is possible with the standard route classes. You could either extend the router, extend the regexp route class or use a controller plugin to manipulate the matched action name; but really it would be much easier if you could change the action names in your controller to match the actions in the URLs.

Comment: Thanks. I will give some time to this question to hang and do some more research before marking it as answered.